# Why is a parameter, derived from java class, seen as non-null type instead of a platform one?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

If java code doesn't mark a parameter as Nullable or NotNull, then it has a so called platform type in kotlin, meaning we can use it as both Nullable and Not Nullable, putting or omitting a question mark at the end of the parameter type respectively.

For example, i have a java class:

```
public class Main{
        public void hi(String[] string){
        }
}
```

and a kotlin class:

```
class A: Main(){
        override fun hi(string: Array<String?>?){
                super.hi(null)
        }
}
```

The kotlin class perfectly gets compiled.

So i was trying to override one of the methods in Android sdk. It is defined in a java class and looks like the following:

```
@UnstableApi
public class DefaultLoadControl implements LoadControl {
...
  @Override
  public void onTracksSelected(
      Timeline timeline,
      MediaPeriodId mediaPeriodId,
      Renderer[] renderers,
      TrackGroupArray trackGroups,
      ExoTrackSelection[] trackSelections) {
    targetBufferBytes =
        targetBufferBytesOverwrite == C.LENGTH_UNSET
            ? calculateTargetBufferBytes(renderers, trackSelections)
            : targetBufferBytesOverwrite;
    allocator.setTargetBufferSize(targetBufferBytes);
  }
...
}
```

I did the next thing expecting that everything will be alright:

```
@UnstableApi
class OwnLoadControl:DefaultLoadControl() {
    override fun onTracksSelected(
        timeline: Timeline,
        mediaPeriodId: MediaSource.MediaPeriodId,
        renderers: Array<out Renderer>,
        trackGroups: TrackGroupArray,
        trackSelections: Array<ExoTrackSelection?>?
    ) {
        super.onTracksSelected(timeline, mediaPeriodId, renderers, trackGroups, null)
    }
}
```

But i get this:

[image]
[image]

For some reason the last parameter is seen as non-null type instead of a platform one, despite it comes from a typical java class. Why ?

**UPD:**
I've got an answer in the comments: "Nullability annotations are not the only way of marking nullability for Kotlin inter-op. They can be defined in a separate file.".

Can someone show me an example of this ?

Comment: Nullability annotations are not the only way of marking nullability for Kotlin inter-op. They can be defined in a separate file. Away from computer right now so I can’t check how they defined it in this library.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I would appreciate it if you would check when you are near a computer. I'm very interested in how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, a different option is used here to indicate non-nullability. Instead of marking a specific element (field, parameter, or return type) as `@NotNull`, non-nullability can be made the default for a specific scope, and that's what has been done [here](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/main/libraries/exoplayer/src/main/java/androidx/media3/exoplayer/package-info.java#L16):

```
@NonNullApi
package androidx.media3.exoplayer;
```

The annotation `@NonNullApi` [ensures](https://github.com/androidx/media/blob/main/libraries/common/src/main/java/androidx/media3/common/util/NonNullApi.java#L26-L29) all elements in the package are non-nullable by default, unless explicitly marked as `@Nullable`. This is why you see such behavior.